Blender Split Rendering Visible but Final Render Transparent
I am rendering an 8k PNG image in Blender which forced it to split render with around 16 segments. When it is rendering each segment, everything seems fine and the render looks like its proceeding smoothly. However, once everything is complete, the final render is transparent and is completely blank


So clearly its rendering but its having issues stitching the images together. I am using GPU Cycles Compute with OpenImageDenoise if that is useful information.

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

Agree, this sounds like a duplicate of radeon prorender render engine - When rendering an image the output is grey - Blender Stack Exchange. Please check the solution provided there, and also the ones linked in that question's duplicate at the very top of the page (it's a very common issue with different sources, as you can see). If none are your case, please [edit] your question with information that would let us know what's going on and we will reopen it if necessary.
